# How to animate the dropdown of a responsive menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I built a responsive navigation bar for a website with html and css.

Everything is working fine, but i want the dropdown of the menu to be animated.

I tried all kinds of variations of transitions(height and all) on different elements, but at best i achieved a delay on the dropdown.

```
  <div class="navigation">
    <div class="toggle"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
    <div class="navitems">
      <div class="nav-itema active"><a href="#">menu</a></div>
      <div class="nav-itema"><a href="#">menu</a></div>
      <div class="nav-itema"><a href="#">menu</a></div>
      <div class="nav-itema"><a href="#">menu</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>


$('.toggle').click(function () {
  $('.navitems').toggleClass('dropmenu');
});
```

css:

```
.navitems{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:no-wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.nav-itema{
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-itema a{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 654px) {
  .toggle{
    display: block;
  }

  .nav-itema{
    text-align: center;
  }

  .navitems{
    display:none;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .dropmenu{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we all know, You can't animate or transition from display none to display block, So we use other methods maybe opacity, or width, or height etc.

Since you're using `JS` for this, it's gonna be pretty simple to achieve.

So the class you add when the button is clicked `.dropmenu` we can add an animation to it, and have it animate whatever property we want.

---

## Opactiy

```js
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  $('.navitems').toggleClass('dropmenu');
});
```

```css
.navitems {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.nav-itema {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-itema a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 654px) {
  .toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-itema {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navitems {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .dropmenu {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    animation: fadein .5s linear;
  }
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="toggle"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
  <div class="navitems">
    <div class="nav-itema active"><a href="#">menu</a></div>
    <div class="nav-itema"><a href="#">menu</a></div>
    <div class="nav-itema"><a href="#">menu</a></div>
    <div class="nav-itema"><a href="#">menu</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

## Transform

Now we can do a lot with transform, the only limit here is your imagination.

```js
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  $('.navitems').toggleClass('dropmenu');
});
```

```css
.navitems {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.nav-itema {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-itema a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 654px) {
  .toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-itema {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navitems {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .dropmenu {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    animation: fadein .5s linear;
  }
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="toggle"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
  <div class="navitems">
    <div class="nav-itema active"><a href="#">menu</a></div>
    <div class="nav-itema"><a href="#">menu</a></div>
    <div class="nav-itema"><a href="#">menu</a></div>
    <div class="nav-itema"><a href="#">menu</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would assume this is enough to get you started, much luck ;)